# Relationships "has-one-through" alternative solution Laravel Voyager

Tags: laravel, voyager

I need to make a relation "has-one-through" but Voyager doesnt support it

The "Consum view" have to show the owner name.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/nFIph.jpg (DB Example)

I've already tried belongsToMany with pivot table but didn`t work!

Show a column from the requested table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why don´t you change your relation, having an owner_id or a house_id instead of an owner_house_id in the consum table? Probably that solves it all.

Comment: Gonna follow your advice and make other changes, Gracias!